# matlab Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent

Tags: matlab, matrix

here is my code:

```
C=@(k) [k,k,2.*k;3,2.*k,5;1,k,k];

AV=@(k,t) [3*t, 6, 9]*C(k)*[3*t ;6 ;9];

avaint=@(k,a,b) quadgk(@(k) AV(k,t),a,b);

AVAR=@(t) avaint(t,0,87600);
```

Is shows:

```
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

when I want to print `AVAR(3)`

Comment: You have misinterpreted the use of anonymous functions. The variables `t` and `x` are not variables in the sense that they can be handled as algebraic variables. When using anonymous functions, MATLAB still expect a numeric output. I think that [symbolic toolbox](http://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html) could be of use here.

Comment: `avaint=@(k,a,b) quadgk(@(k) AV(k,t),a,b);` should be `avaint=@(t,a,b) quadgk(@(k) AV(k,t),a,b);`.  With that change, I reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

### Source of Error

The `quadgk` function passes a vector of integration points to the function handle given to it.
From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadgk.html):

> The function y = fun(x) should accept a vector argument x and return a vector result y, where y is the integrand evaluated at each element of x.

This creates the dimension mismatch causing the error.

### Solutions

To get around this implementation, you can perform the numerical integration using the [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) function with the (`'ArrayValued'`,`true`) option pair:

```
avaint = @(t,a,b) integral(@(k) AV(k,t),a,b,'ArrayValued',true);
```

Or, you can use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) within `AV` to abide by the requirement of `quadgk`:

```
AV = @(k,t) arrayfun(@(k_el) [3*t, 6, 9]*(C(k_el)*[3*t ;6 ;9]),k);
```